# Difference between TcpCommunicationSpi(CommunicationSpi) and TcpDiscoverySpi(DiscoverySpi)

Tags: ignite

In ignite documentation writes that TcpCommunicationSpi(CommunicationSpi) uses the TCP/IP to communicate with other nodes,and  TcpDiscoverySpi(DiscoverySpi)  uses the  TCP/IP for node discovery. I think that 2(comunicate and discovery) ideas are almost same.

Please meaty tell me what is difference between TcpCommunicationSpi(CommunicationSpi) and  TcpDiscoverySpi(DiscoverySpi) and usages?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TcpDiscoverySpi is used by nodes in order to build and maintain a cluster of them. The messages that are sent over this SPI are system/internal and they are sent from one node to other (neighbor on the left). So it means that the cluster is organized as a ring and TcpDiscoverySpi is used to exchange internal information between the nodes.

On the other hand when a node needs to send a message directly to the other (cache put/get, compute, event, etc.) it uses TcpCommunicationSpi opening a direct connection to the remote node.

Comment: Thank you for answer. But one question,(please take into account that I am new in Ignite) I understood from your answer that TcpDiscoverySpi used for building cluster,and TcpCommunicationSpi for operations with caches?...If it is so,how I managed using only DiscoverySpi I build cluster with 2 remote nodes on server and one client mode(local node) and I successfully did puts/gets between nodes(when my caches are replicated or partitioned).  And I didnt use CommunicatuonSpi. I think that DiscoverySpi normally understood.but ComunicationSpi is unsertine for me.

Comment: And please show me visual one example using TcpCommunicationSpi.

Comment: @daniels, both discovery and communication SPIs are always used by the kernel. If you don't setup communication SPI explicitly it doesn't mean that it won't be used by Ignite. In the case when you don't specify discovery and communication SPIs explicitly the ones with default settings (port numbers, IPs, network timeouts, etc.) are used.
Here you can see an example on how TcpCommunicationSpi is set in configuration
https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/cluster-config#isolated-ignite-clusters-on-the-same-set-of-machin

Comment: I saw that example. Local port 49500  of DiscoverySpi(in a.xml)  explicitly used by other configuration(b.xml) for finding nodes configured on this port by ipFinder.  
I understood  this,but when we add CommunicationSpi( in a.xml) ,where explicitly used 49100 port by other configurations(f.e. b.xml)? Iin b.xml what I should do ,how can I explicitly use this port?

Comment: You change communication SPI's port only if the default one is blocked by firewalls or used by some other process. If you change communication SPI's port in one configuration A then all the other nodes will use this port to connect to the nodes started with this configuration (basically, the communication port number will be sent to other nodes automatically after a node joined the topology using discovery SPI)